# iOS universal links: excluded paths open my app

Tags: ios-universal-links

Here is my AASA file (my appID changed):

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [ "A123B4567C.app.myapp.tool" ],
                "components": [
                    { "/": "/en", "exclude": true },
                    { "/": "/en/*", "exclude": true },
                    { "/": "/workspace/*", "exclude": true },
                    { "/": "*" }
                ],
                "paths": [ "NOT /en", "NOT /en/*", "NOT /workspace/*", "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to open all links with my app except those with excluded flag.

When I open 'right' links, my app opens them (that's great).

When I open excluded link (e.g. https://myapp.app/workspace/personal) Safari opens it (that's great) but then the app is launched (that's what not expected).

What I already checked:

- added the old "paths" property (it wasn't there originally)
- rebooted my device
- reinstalled my app from the TestFlight and then from the AppStore
- asked ChatGPT
- used AASA validator (branch.io one)
- cleared Safari cache
- checked my links for redirects
- posted a question on Apple Developer Forum (no answer yet)

What else can I check? Thanks.